# Where does the simulator save files (Xcode not updating files)?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode4.2

I am having some trouble with Xcode not updating files that I have updated (e.g. database, jpgs etc), even though I have carefully deleted the old files and removed the references. This problem consists since Xcode  > 4.2.

Is there a place (maybe hidden files) where the simulator drops data except the derived data folder and

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/[OS version]/Applications/[appGUID]/
```

Many thanks in advance

PS: yes, I usually clean project, delete derived data, delete all simulator files in the abov directory, delete the project and restart the mac. And still there seems to be  a reference to the old data (like jpg, database etc), even if I can't find it on the file system...

Comment: Try the application at real device. If problem persists, double check if files are really updated, both retina and normal versions. I'm forgoting replace retina versions of images sometimes.

Comment: Do you delete the app from the simulator -- press on the app's icon until it jiggles, then press the "X"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Goto Product>>Clean Build Folder. Or alternatively, Reset Simulator from iOS Simulator menu. That way your app will be rendered new in the simulator and used after a complete refresh and link-up with your project files.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the app in the simulator. That way you get rid of everything.

Answer (score 1):

Some times you have conflicting code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions that you forgot to remove. Make sure that function only has the statements you want.

For example, the code below is setting the background to white. No matter what you add to the storyboard you will still see all white.

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:       (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
      self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
      // Override point for customization after application launch.
      self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
      [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
      return YES;
    }
```

Change it to:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the app in the simulator and then goto Product>>Clean. This works for me.

Comment: Though you have answered the question; please provide additional details about the resolution and why it will resolve set issue for further clarification.